# Align Twitter, FB Share, LinkedIn buttons

Tags: html, css, facebook

I've looked different options for aligning the FB share button with the other social media buttons, but none have worked for me yet. I'm only a few pixels off. Any ideas?

```
<div style="float:left; vertical-align:top">

<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-url="{my url}" data-text="{text}" data-count="none" data-hashtags="{hashtag}" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>

</div>

<div style="float:left; padding: 0 0 0 5px; vertical-align:top">

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="{my url}" data-layout="button"></div>

</div>

<div style="float:left; padding: 0 5px; vertical-align:top">

<script type="IN/Share" data-url="{my url}"></script>

</div>
```

!Social Media alignment[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntzCM.png)

Comment: would you make a fiddle? would be easier to help you with your problem.

Comment: Sure! How do I do that?

Comment: Well, the easiest way - go to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and recreate your problem, the best way is to include only those parts of your code which are related to your problem.

Comment: All right, so the weird thing is that it looks fine in jsfiddle, still doesn't look fine on my site. Any idea why that may be? http://jsfiddle.net/ozz4bspm/ Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm, is your website published? If yes, can you post a link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61150/discussion-between-ramis-wachtler-and-m00nbeam360).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `.fb_iframe_widget` class to this

```
.fb_iframe_widget {
    display: inline-flex; /* changed line */
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for. You rock!

Comment: I had to add `!important` as well for this to work, like this: `display: inline-flex !important;`

Answer (score 0):

The facebook button has still a misalignment of one pixel.
Just add this to the css class above:

top: -1px;

P.S.: wanted to add this as a comment but I couldn't because not enough "reputation" points.